# Mysql multiple Inner Joins not working

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have following query that is working fine in TSQL

```
SELECT     
    shoppingcart_1.price, shoppingcart_1.stid, course.isbn, 
    book.BookTitle, course.Course_ID, schedule.stid AS Expr1
FROM         
    book 
INNER JOIN 
    shoppingcart AS shoppingcart_1 
INNER JOIN 
    schedule ON shoppingcart_1.cid = schedule.course_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    course ON schedule.course_ID = course.Course_ID 
    ON book.isbn = course.isbn
WHERE     
    (shoppingcart_1.stid = '20070004')
```

but when I run it in Mysql it displays error on line

```
INNER JOIN course ON schedule.course_ID = course.Course_ID ON book.isbn = course.isbn
```

Error text is

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'ON book.isbn = course.isbn WHERE (shoppingcart_1.stid =
>   '20070004') LIMIT 0' at line 6

I am writing queries first time in mysql, please help

Comment: You're missing the `ON` for your join to `shoppingcart`

Comment: I must wonder, did you even try to figure out what was wrong?

Comment: I have seen many times , i compared this query to sql server query again after reading your comments. But it is working exactly on sql server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have your joins a little mixed up. I tried cleaning it up. See if this works for you

```
SELECT shoppingcart_1.price, shoppingcart_1.stid, course.isbn, book.BookTitle, course.Course_ID, schedule.stid AS Expr1
FROM book 
INNER JOIN course ON book.isbn = course.isbn
INNER JOIN schedule ON course.Course_ID = schedule.course_ID  
INNER JOIN shoppingcart AS shoppingcart_1 ON schedule.course_ID = shoppingcart_1.cid
WHERE shoppingcart_1.stid = '20070004'
```

Note how I join book to course, then course to schedule, then schedule to shoppingcart. Then use the WHERE clause to specify other conditions.

Comment: Thanks @shredder , your suggested query is working without eror. But it also fetches other records from Shoppingcart table, not only against '20070004'. Please help how i can fix it?

Comment: I just noticed I had duplicated a join in the where clause. Sorry about that, see how it works with this edit.

Comment: this is returning same result. Shoppingcart is a junction table and i have to load other details from relevant tables to display

Comment: Thanks for your concern, your solution helped me to find out the issue